# How to display category ,subcategory and image on magento 1.9 on home page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, cms

I have to display category,subcategory and image on home page.I am using custom theme.

Foe example: My home page category,subcategory and image display is like below

Cat1                    Cat2                        Cat3
  Subcat1  Image           Subcat1      Image          Subcat1    Image
  SubCat2                  Subcat2                     Subcat2
  Subcat3                  SUbcat3                     Subcat3

Please help me how to do it.Its urgent please give me idea how to do it.

Many Thanks,
Padma

Comment: I am using custom theme.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.
Add a custom `catalog/homecategories.phtml` file and add it in your `local.xml`.

`homecategories.phtml`

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
/** @var $helper Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category */

$topCategories = $helper->getStoreCategories(true);
?>

<?php if (!empty($topCategories)): ?>
    <div class="home-categories">

        <ul class="level-1">
            <?php foreach ($topCategories as $topCategory): ?>
                <?php /** @var $topCategory \Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */ ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($topCategory); ?>"><?php echo $topCategory->getName(); ?></a>

                    <?php if ($topCategory->hasChildren()): ?>
                        <ul class="level-2">
                            <?php foreach ($topCategory->getCategories($topCategory, 0, true) as $category): ?>
                                <?php /** @var $category \Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */ ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($category); ?>"><?php echo $category->getName(); ?></a>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($category); ?>">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $category->getImageUrl();?>" alt="" />
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
```

`local.xml`

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="home-categories" as="home_categories" before="-">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/homecategories.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```