# Sub Category image Show in Page using phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am using template phtml added php code. this call from static block.Url and link works fine but It's not view any sub category image. I want to show sub category images.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(12);
$subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
if (count($subcategories) > 0){     
  foreach($subcategories as $subcategory) { ?>
```

```
 <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $subcategory->getURL(); ?>" > 
                   

   <img alt="" src="<?php echo $subcategory->getImageUrl(); ?>" />                               
 </a>
                  
   <a href="<?php echo $subcategory->getURL(); ?>" > <?php   echo $subcategory->getName(); ?> </a>
                
              
      <?php echo '</div>' ?>
```

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/60957/85907

Comment: This link is same like my image tag.I can access everthing without image file

Answer (score 0):

Please replace below code

```
<img alt="" src="<?php echo $subcategory->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
```

to

```
<?php $mediaurl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);?>
<img alt="" src="<?php echo $mediaurl."catalog/category/".$subcategory->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
```

Comment: After change your code inspect browser show location "https://www.domainame.com/media/catalog/category/" .this can't acess my sub category images.

Comment: change getImageUrl() to getImage()

Comment: getImage() isn't also effect any changes

Comment: I added your code with manually image show properlly <img alt="" src="<?php echo $mediaurl."catalog/category/".'iphone-pro-max_1.jpg'; ?>" /> .I want to programatically view image.This category location image access.It will work

Comment: Please give me website detials I will check it